Data output after TJavaFlex
I use a TJavaFlex with different parts like in the images.
In the System.out.println, i have all lines (2000) but the TLogRow have nothing and not all lines. I dont know why.




Hi I think your problem comes from the way you use the tJavaFlex.
The tJavaFlex has three parts :

Start Code : the code in this part is executed at the initialization of the component
Main Code : it loops on the data flow and allows to apply code on it
End Code : runs at the end (after the flow is processed)

So when you put :
row8.email = a.getMail();
row8.idAttempt = a.getIdAttemps();

It tries to put values in a already "closed" flow.
I tried to replicate what you are trying to do

And when you put your output row8 (in my case row9) in the main part the tLogRow after shows you a "full" output

So try putting something like this in the main part of the tJavaFlex :
row8.email = userObj.getString("mail");
row8.idAttempt = userObj.getString("_id");

Hope this helps

Thanks you !  i resolve this problem with an other method. In my TExtractJsonField, i use XPath and i loop on my attempts and to have my user properties , I do ../user/id.
